# probability of prime factor

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, prime-factorization, probability-limit-theorems

Question, what are the chances for obtaining the same, prime factor 55049? 
The SUM of List A gives a factor of 17 x 55049 and the sum of list B gives a factor of 19 x 55049

I want to understand how to quantify the probability of attaining the same prime factor of two randomly generated number series, in two seperate lists. The lists are independent of each other. The sum of two lists, gives a number with a prime factor. How do i quantify the probability for the prime factor to be the same. In this case I generated two list which is randomly produced, by numpy, uniform distribution.

The numbers in list A is produced, by   uniform distrubtion with added noise of about 1, the probability distribution is uniform. 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html#numpy.random.uniform

Next for list B, all the random numbers is produced by a predetermined multiple of 19.  The numerical values shifts sometimes with 1000's and 100. And is always a factor of 19. The number 19 is multiplied by a random number, with numpy random generator, how this time it is sampled by uniform distribution,

So programming wise it would look something like random.randint(1,200) = X

X * 19 = entries in B.

Now you know how both numbers in both list, A and B is generated.

The SUM of List A gives a factor of 17 x 55049 and the sum of list B gives a factor of 19 x 55049

What are the probability for attaining the same factor, of  55049? 55049 is also a prime, 17, 19 with twin-primes.

For both randomly picked integers it is, 1/pA * 1/pB = 1/p 
where pA=pB

How do I take into consideration the series distribution of numbers, list A and B giving this factor? Given the fact from the list A is produced entirely by random generator, along with list B, however with a preconditioned prime factor of 19.

A = [5, 11, 24, 58, 106, 123, 243, 244, 249, 292, 293, 306, 321, 336, 354, 374, 417, 421, 496, 532, 545, 566, 583, 587, 641, 659, 675, 711, 728, 744, 749, 757, 784, 810, 833, 869, 879, 929, 978, 1016, 1019, 1047, 1050, 1055, 1077, 1099, 1102, 1117, 1156, 1167, 1177, 1220, 1244, 1249, 1254, 1255, 1272, 1288, 1326, 1338, 1348, 1394, 1430, 1439, 1440, 1446, 1484, 1486, 1573, 1591, 1621, 1622, 1635, 1636, 1646, 1748, 1752, 1762, 1766, 1788, 1820, 1839, 1848, 1852, 1874, 1897, 1934, 1941, 1950, 1969, 1970, 1979, 2018, 2081, 2085, 2147, 2176, 2202, 2203, 2252, 2257, 2285, 2300, 2316, 2319, 2320, 2322, 2332, 2345, 2400, 2406, 2425, 2428, 2466, 2473, 2507, 2528, 2532, 2551, 2561, 2571, 2602, 2603, 2610, 2614, 2657, 2665, 2717, 2747, 2752, 2767, 2807, 2811, 2816, 2818, 2825, 2846, 2862, 2896, 2913, 2952, 2961, 3005, 3020, 3022, 3027, 3047, 3087, 3113, 3119, 3138, 3171, 3220, 3255, 3270, 3285, 3426, 3433, 3465, 3491, 3509, 3522, 3531, 3544, 3563, 3641, 3651, 3694, 3698, 3714, 3715, 3728, 3743, 3761, 3763, 3780, 3824, 3828, 3841, 3852, 3862, 3874, 3904, 3916, 3948, 3971, 4008, 4050, 4109, 4122, 4154, 4158, 4167, 4183, 4192, 4193, 4209, 4215, 4238, 4259, 4268, 4307, 4328, 4330, 4347, 4365, 4382, 4398, 4418, 4463, 4480, 4522, 4527, 4618, 4632, 4672, 4676, 4699, 4739, 4762, 4775, 4784, 4788, 4844, 4888, 4890, 4896, 4906, 4907, 4913, 4928, 4957, 4993, 4998, 5015, 5052, 5084, 5106, 5135, 5167, 5174, 5207, 5227, 5230, 5272, 5308, 5317, 5324, 5353, 5395, 5408, 5460, 5464, 5509, 5536, 5565, 5594, 5597, 5602, 5616, 5638, 5648, 5658, 5664, 5690, 5692, 5710, 5716, 5753, 5763, 5793, 5854, 5863, 5874, 5880, 5895, 5903, 5939, 5945, 5947, 5963, 5990, 6033, 6037, 6043, 6064, 6087, 6125, 6130, 6149, 6161, 6189, 6195, 6208]

B = [836, 2641, 7809, 5871, 1938, 4541, 8189, 11894, 2261, 6042, 12863, 8018, 7923, 1995, 5510, 13148, 3743, 3439, 8778, 3116, 2394, 4826, 8569, 14915, 2280, 1938, 16074, 7923, 3363, 6954, 6650, 2679, 4104, 5206, 7999, 6517, 3515, 7030, 4712, 3211, 3762, 5035, 6270, 5643, 6289, 7391, 6897, 10241, 3021, 7334, 5358, 8816, 3040, 3838, 5092, 3477, 5377, 2527, 7448, 4351, 5130, 3857, 6973, 4104, 1900, 1463, 3743, 6289, 1976, 2261, 4009, 4180, 2660, 5719, 3553, 3477, 4332, 4294, 836, 4598, 2052, 1653, 931, 1767, 1482, 836, 7809, 2090, 3059, 4104, 8436, 4560, 1615, 3914, 4085, 1976, 3496, 3990, 7448, 2109, 2679, 4636, 1615, 2527, 2603, 1843, 4579, 2109, 1045, 2375, 3572, 5339, 2090, 1425, 2375, 8265, 3534, 3933, 2109, 5358, 2983, 2204, 2698, 7942, 6517, 2033, 4750, 7049, 2489, 3857, 2204, 5795, 2546, 1843, 9443, 5358, 13281, 3648, 5206, 3762, 2489, 4123, 1406, 513, 1273, 342, 1197, 2375, 1786, 1691, 855, 6441, 4921, 1767, 7144, 3059, 1520, 5757, 6783, 2831, 2698, 2755, 2698, 1254, 5472, 2128, 5681, 4104, 4484, 3363, 3325, 7315, 3686, 2052, 817, 2318, 2166, 1026, 3135, 2071, 1026, 950, 1767, 1026, 1026, 2926, 1615, 1653, 3819, 2413, 9576, 4446, 7980, 4332, 2166, 5016, 3002, 9025, 2622, 2831, 12046, 1957, 1691, 3591, 1919, 3059, 3116, 1634, 855, 1748, 779, 6460, 8360, 4142, 3040, 2223, 3040, 2527, 836, 1520, 3002, 665, 152, 1805, 4864, 1254, 817, 931, 798, 1330, 1463, 2318, 1159, 627, 513, 2375, 5396, 6422, 6593, 2546, 4902, 3249, 4256, 6726, 1425, 1368, 3002, 931, 2432, 1425, 1805, 2793, 4237, 950, 494, 836, 1178, 1843, 3363, 1615, 304, 475, 2394, 969, 2242, 1558, 2831, 836, 323, 1653, 76, 817, 1425, 3439, 2109, 1026, 1045, 779, 133, 76, 1444, 874, 228, 2090, 551, 361, 1292, 1349, 1026, 1862, 1995, 2223, 1349, 1330]

What I am looking for is if there is a theoritical way to quantify the probability for attaining the same prime factor of two randomly generated lists.

The bounds for list A, is (1, 141) random numbers, for list B, X is (4, 846) random int numbers. Using np.random.randint(a,b), python

I was tipped to look at the birthday paradox. It makes sense the greater pool size of numbers, to pick from, the chances for gaining the same prime factor is greater. But this expirement relates to comparing to sums to each other. Confined to this expirement only. And according to this paradox, the chances of that, is practically , zero near n=2.

Comment: $24$ isn't a factor of $17\cdot 55049$. I don't get this question at all.

Comment: The sum of list A gives a prime factor of 17 x 55049 and the sum of list B gives a prime factor of 19 x 55049.

Comment: Could you just write down a very short introduction stating what you are trying to do? It is quite difficult for me to read and figure that out for myself.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: My guess is that OP has generated two lists, apparently independently, in the manner described, and their sums are both coincidentally a multiple of $55049$.  OP is presumably wondering how startling this coincidence is.

Comment: Exactly. Brain.

Comment: @Brian Thanks! To answer that we would need a bound in the size the generated numbers can be. And also if being both a multiple of $3 $ is considered startling and if not, where the line is drawn.

Comment: Could you make another experiment to see if the phenomenon occurs again? If so it is likely that the two random processes are not so independent. Also what is the point of multiplying by $19 $ artificially if you are going to break down the result into primes in the end anyway?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Thanks so much for considering. This question is really interesting to me, I found the book "Statistical Independence in Probability, Analysis and Number" very intriguing, so I just played around with python and statistcal generators. Then i found this factor, with the randomly generated list. 

The upper bound, i remember, was for list B, random.rand(4,846) and low, up-bound. 
For list A, it is entirely, randomly genrated, with around 30 difference, and 1, between that number. It is always increases. Added to the previous number.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I really don't know why I did that at the time, it was 1 month ago, I saved the list. And I tried to quantify the probability.   I am not sure how random numpy random generators are. I am actually in the process of producing a algorithm that does this expirement a million times and try to find expirementally, how many times I can get the same factor out through million expirements.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier That way I can maybe get a sense for how probable this gaining this factor is, from two independent lists.

Comment: Python's random module use Mersenne Twister algorithm. Check also the Birthday Paradox.

Comment: @ ArnaudMortier I guess the line is drawn when i achieve the same factor with at least 4 digit number. This is 5 digit number. Highly unsual. The for loops made my computer very slow, I am currently figuring out other ways to repeat this expirement tens millions of times. Any ideas for a more efficient algorithm it is very welcomed.

Comment: @usiro very interesting, thanks for the tip. This gave me a sense of the problem, take million expirements of the above problem, the probability for achieving the same factor, regardless of the size is of-course very high. But with only two, according to this, is nearly zero.

Comment: @usiro that I made expirements x100 k with, relating two lists, not lists between expirements, then according to the paradox, the probability would be higher. So within the scope, as I initially started with.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145510/random-is-barely-random-at-all) out. I hope it will give you some idea on the code you are working on.

Comment: It makes sense the greater pool size of numbers, to pick from, the chances for gaining the same prime factor is greater. Because the factorials, !n, reveal for n, being large, greater combinations and thus repeating a factor within a scope of expirements is surprisingly probable. I understand that. 

 But this expirement relates to comparing to sums to each other. Confined to this expirement only. Repeating this expirement millions of times but only comparing the prime factor for n=2, in a room, this is what I am interested in. Not comparing factors between expirements. Do you understand?

Comment: Have tried to execute the code using different version of Python or on the another machine?

Comment: I don't think it have anything to do with the twister-algorithm. Just pure luck I guess. If I calculate the probability right now, assuming 1/pA * 1/pB = 1/30303924. Where pA=pB, then it is = 303039, times more likely for you to be hit by lightning than this factor being the same, assuming you have done this expirement on first try.

Comment: See this, for n=2, people in the room. Comparison of two lists that are described like above. Made a script for this. I ran this for about, half a day, and manged to get a prime factor of size about 4 digits big, the biggest prime, was 4500 range. Produced 2 millions lists.  I will try for 10 million more expirements, to see if I can get a factor close to 30000, like I gained above, 5 digit range, 55049, randomly, once. After first, try. Still can't believe my luck.

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/RedY5hp7)  here is the python script

Comment: Produced witht the algorithm as of now, three prime factors in the 5 digit range. Here: [22051]
[60779]
[3, 3, 14369]

Comment: It might be something to do with your script - have you used debugger to trace variables? For example you are using "i" couple times in a 'for' loop, but the value of variable "i" is never empty (such i==0) before you use for next function, so it may consist a value that is carried out to another method.

Comment: no i checked, works, they are all different. And the loops close. So it is all good. The second last loop, should be like that, because I am comparing the factors with the second list.